# React-Native toggle between grid and list views

Tags: react-native

I want to implement a button that switches my list view to grid from list and vice-versa.
And my Items are Cards with images and info below them
What is the best way to implement this ?

Should I have two flatLists one for grid and one for list with different settings. Or is there a better way to handle this like an already existing component ?

Comment: How does your code currently looks like? Please share a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: my code is just a normal FlatList (not a grid), it has nothing special

Answer (score 0):

You have to create two different flatList and than call a boolean to switch from one to an other:

```
Enum DisplayType {
  grid,
  list
}

const yourComponent = () => {

  const [displayType, setDisplayType] = useState<DisplayType>(DisplayType.grid);

  return (
    <>
      {displayType === DisplayType.grid ? <MyFlatListInGrid /> : <MyFlatListInList />}
    </>
  )

}
```

I have experienced other way to do this but this is the best by far and the less "laggy" one.